# Dynamic binding Ninject

Tags: c#, .net

I'm building a large service, and using Ninjcet:

```
Bind<IMyObject>().To<MyObject>();
```

Because my logic layer is quite big, and will grow, I would like to automatically create bindings within an assembly, given that the class implements an interface.

```
public void LoadAssembly()
{
  string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(binFolder, "Logic.dll",     SearchOption.AllDirectories);
  foreach (var file in files)
  {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
    if (fileName != null && fileName.Contains("Logic"))
    {
      DynamicallyBindManagers(Assembly.LoadFrom(file));
    }
  }
}

private void DynamicallyBindManagers(Assembly assembly)
{
  var classes = FindClassesWithInterfacesInAssembly(assembly);

  // Remove unwanted classes
  for (var i = classes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    if (classes[i].Name.Contains("`"))
    {
      classes.Remove(classes[i]);
    }
  }

  foreach (var cl in classes)
  {
    var interfaces = cl.GetInterfaces();

    foreach (var myInterface in interfaces)
    {
      if (classes.Any(c => c.Name == intf.Name.Remove(0, 1)))
      {
         var myClass = classes.First(c => c.Name == intf.Name.Remove(0, 1));           
         Bind<myInterface >().To<myClass>(); //How can I get Bind to accept myInterface & myClass
      }
    }
  }
}

private List<Type> FindClassesWithInterfacesInAssembly(Assembly assembly)
{
  var classes = new List<Type>();

  foreach (var ti in assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsClass))
  {
    if (ti.GetInterfaces().Any())
    {
      classes.Add(ti);
    }
   }
   return classes;
  }
```

All help appreciated.

Comment: Please describe what exactly you need help with. Are you getting an exception? Does the code compile and run but Ninject complains about missing bindings? etc.

Comment: My problem is that I would like to be able, instead of having to manually put all bindings e.g. Bind<IMyObject>().To<MyObject>(); I would like to find all classes that implement an interface, and Bind those to the interface they implement, given the interface has the same name as the class + I. In my demo above, I have the interfaces, and classes from the assembly, but I need to be able to add use those in the Bind<>().To<>();

Comment: You should look into the `Ninject.Extensions.Conventions` namespace - get the *Conventions* extension and you can do what I think you want to do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Ninject Conventions extension you can do

```
Bind (x => x.FromThisAssembly.SelectAllClasses.BindDefaultInterface));
```

Which binds all `ISomething` to `Something`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Used this: to solve my problem: kernel.Bind(x => x
    .FromAssembliesMatching("*")
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .BindDefaultInterface());